# Generic filter function

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create for my api filtering. I've found bunch of approaches to write generic sorting and now i have to create generic filtering. How can i make it?

```cs
public static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var parametr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var property = Expression.Property(parametr, propertyName);
    var propObject = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(propObject, parametr);
}

public static IQueryable<T> ApplyOrdering<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, 
    string propertyName, bool desc = false)
{
    return desc ?
        source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T>(propertyName))
        : source.OrderByDescending(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));
}

public static IQueryable<T> ApplySearching<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string value)
{   
    return source.Where(ToLambda<T>(value));
}
```

Can't figure out, how i should work with where is this fucntion. How to use, for instance, Contains methods and etc?

Comment: Add more samples how do you plan to use that. You have found only basic examples how to work with ExpressionTree.

Comment: Also, please note that are are plenty examples available on the web, including Stack Overflow questions on the same topic.